# How to detect missing LOG4J2 config?

Tags: java, log4j2

I would like to be able to detect when the app is missing a LOG4J2.XML configuration file, and in that case set some other defaults than what LOG4J2 has otherwise.

Basically, I would like to run this code if a config file isnt found:

```
    // A default configuration that shows ALL Logger output, without a XML config!
    LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getLoggerConfig(LogManager.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME); 
    loggerConfig.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    ctx.updateLoggers();  // This causes all Loggers to refetch information from their LoggerConfig.
```

How can I detect that LOG4J2 failed to load a configuration?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps `if (config instanceof DefaultConfiguration)` might do the trick.

Comment: That was clever, add it as an answer and I'll select it. config is an instance of XmlConfiguration when the LOG4J2.XML is found in the classpath, or DefaultConfiguration otherwise.

Comment: Just a note for future people - if you are getting an error with the method getContext() not existing, you need to swap out the org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.LoggerContext import with org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like ...

```
if (config instanceof DefaultConfiguration)
```

...would be enough, since DefaultConfiguration is used whenever there is nothing else available, see the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) for Log4j2 configuration:

> If no configuration file could be located the `DefaultConfiguration`
>   will be used. This will cause logging output to go to the console.

Comment: For most people it is enough to use the default without extra configuration, but the DefaultConfiguration is also set to skip DEBUG-level entries, which I wanted in this case.