# log4j2 not writing in file when using a separate class

Tags: java, selenium, logging, log4j2

I am currently trying to learn using Selenium. And for that, I get to use log4j2 in order to log what is going well, and what is not. 
Everything worked fine, as long as everything was in the same class. I could see my logs in the console, and my log file was well written. But as soon as I tried to write a separate class in order to give structure to my code, everything went wrong. It's like my custom XML properties file isn't found anymore.

Here is the code of my XML properties file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="debug">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">log</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="file-log" fileName="${log-path}/logfile.log"
        filePattern="${log-path}/logfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />

            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
        </RollingFile>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="phptravels" level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="file-log" level="info"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And here is a sample of my "initial" code, which was working just as I wanted :

```
package phptravels;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import outils.Log;


public class PhpTravelsJunit {
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
     private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\scointe\\Documents\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize() ;
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.setProperty("log4j2.configuration", "C:\\Users\\scointe\\Documents\\Eclipse\\SeleniumPractice\\properties\\log4j2.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void PhpTravelsJunit() throws Exception {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PhpTravelsJunit.class);
        startTestCase(log, "PhpTravels - Parcours articles");
        driver.navigate().to("http://automationpractice.com/");
        log.info("Redirection sur l'url du site");
        //on remplit le champ de recherche avec le texte "dress" et on clique sur le bouton de recherche
        driver.findElement(By.id("search_query_top")).sendKeys("dress");
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit_search")).click();
        log.info("Recherche des articles comportant le texte \"dress\"");

        //on trie les résultats pas prix croissant
        Select order = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selectProductSort")));
        order.selectByValue("price:asc");
        log.info("Tri des résultats par prix croissant");


        //On se place sur le menu flottant "Women" pour sélectionner la catégorie "Tops" qui apparaît
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);      
        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.className("sf-with-ul"))).perform();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        WebElement tops = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block_top_menu']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a")));
        actions.moveToElement(tops).perform();
        tops.click();
        log.info("Clic sur la catégorie \"Tops\" dans le menu flottant \"Women\"");

        //On applique un filtre sur la couleur, pour n'avoir que des articles noirs
        driver.findElement(By.id("layered_id_attribute_group_11")).click();
        log.info("Filtre sur la couleur. Noir uniquement");

        endTestCase(log);

        //...

    }

    public static void startTestCase(Logger log, String caseName) {
        log.info("****************************************************************************************");

        log.info("-------------------------                 "+caseName+ "       -------------------------");

        log.info("****************************************************************************************");
    }

    public static void endTestCase(Logger log) {
        log.info("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             "+"-E---N---D-"+"             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        log.info("X");

        log.info("X");

        log.info("");

        log.info("");

    }
}
```

Then, I decided to write a new class called "Log" which was supposed to managage all the Logger tasks, which looks like this :

```
package outils;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Log {
    private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName());
    //private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");

    public static void startTestCase(String caseName) {
        Log.info("****************************************************************************************");

        Log.info("-------------------------                 "+caseName+ "       -------------------------");

        Log.info("****************************************************************************************");
    }

    public static void endTestCase() {
        Log.info("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX             "+"-E---N---D-"+"             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        Log.info("X");

        Log.info("X");

        Log.info("");

        Log.info("");

    }

    public static void info(String msg) {
        Log.info(msg);
    }

    public static void warn(String msg) {
        Log.warn(msg);
    }

    public static void error(String msg) {
        Log.error(msg);
    }

    public static void fatal(String msg) {
        Log.fatal(msg);
    }

    public static void debug(String msg) {
        Log.debug(msg);
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the code of my new class, which only executes the test case shown in the code sample above :

```
public class PhpTravelsNavigation {
    private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
     private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    private static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\scointe\\Documents\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize() ;
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.setProperty("log4j2.configuration", "C:\\Users\\scointe\\Documents\\Eclipse\\SeleniumPractice\\properties\\log4j2.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void PhpTravelsNavigation() throws Exception {
        Log.startTestCase("PhpTravels - Parcours articles");
        driver.navigate().to("http://automationpractice.com/");
        Log.info("Redirection sur l'url du site");
        //on remplit le champ de recherche avec le texte "dress" et on clique sur le bouton de recherche
        driver.findElement(By.id("search_query_top")).sendKeys("dress");
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit_search")).click();
        Log.info("Recherche des articles comportant le texte \"dress\"");

        //on trie les résultats pas prix croissant
        Select order = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selectProductSort")));
        order.selectByValue("price:asc");
        Log.info("Tri des résultats par prix croissant");


        //On se place sur le menu flottant "Women" pour sélectionner la catégorie "Tops" qui apparaît
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);      
        actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.className("sf-with-ul"))).perform();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        WebElement tops = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='block_top_menu']/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]/a")));
        actions.moveToElement(tops).perform();
        tops.click();
        Log.info("Clic sur la catégorie \"Tops\" dans le menu flottant \"Women\"");

        //On applique un filtre sur la couleur, pour n'avoir que des articles noirs
        driver.findElement(By.id("layered_id_attribute_group_11")).click();
        Log.info("Filtre sur la couleur. Noir uniquement");

        Log.endTestCase();


    }



    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        //driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
        }

    }

}
```

As I said, with the new code, I only get to see the logs in the console, and I don't have any writing in my log file anymore. The file is created, but stays empty. Actually, it even overwrites the existing file with the same name if there is one, when my working code only creates a new one.

Do You have any idea of what could cause that ? 
I'm not an expert in Java, or coding in general, but all answers would be welcome.

If you need any extra information, just ask me !

Thanks in advance :)

Edit : After a few tests, I can confirm that my configuration file is not used by my Log class. How can I fix that ? I have even transformed it into a non static class and instanciate it with a constructor. But it doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your imports `org.apache.log4j.Logger` and your code `Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PhpTravelsJunit.class);` it seems that you are using Log4j 1, but your configuration file is Log4j 2 style.

You should either use Log4j 2's `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` and `org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager`, and `LogManager.getLogger(PhpTravelsJunit.class)` or switch to Log4j 1 (not the best option).

Of course you need appropriate dependencies/jars for either of them.

PS: sorry, I made a mistake by writting `LogManager.getRootLogger` instead of `LogManager.getLogger`.

Comment: Well, I tried to use log4j 1 at first, but I was getting error messages asking for a configuration file named "log4j2.properties" or "log4j2.xml" (I don't remember which one). So I just tried to follow tutorials for log4j2. I had to fight with my configuration file to finally get it working though. What is wrong in my usage of log4j then ?

Comment: Your code is using Log4j 1, but your configuration is for Log4j 2. Choose one.

Comment: But I don't really understand the difference between the two of them in the code. With log4j2, do I have to use LogManager ?
edit : oh sorry I didn't see your edit. I'll try that

Comment: So I edited my code to use only log4j2. And I thank you for this information. But it doesn't seem to solve my issue. It is still like my configuration file isn't used when using my two new classes. It doesn't create a new file anymore though.

Comment: @Koma where exactly is your log4j2.xml file? And where are the classes situated? Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250527/how-to-detect-missing-log4j2-config) to check if the default config is used.

Comment: My xml file is in a folder named "properties" which is in my project. The class "Log" is in a package named "outils", and all my test classes (PhpTravelsJUnit, PhpTravelsNavigate, ...) are in a package called "phptravels". Both packages are in the src folder of my project. 
Thanks for the link, I'll go take a look !

Comment: According to your link, and the result I got, the configuration used by Eclipse is not the default one. But at the same time, I tried sliding a little identifier in the display of my logs so I could check if my config file was used or not. And it seems it is not used. (i get the right display when using my old code)

Comment: Your log4j2.xml file should be in root folder. In your case in `src` folder.

Comment: It has been moved, according to what you said. But unfortunately my issue remains the same :/ - Thank you so much for the time you spend trying to figure this out with me.

Comment: Try following the format specified in [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) and [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML) pages. It may be the case that some lower/upper case letters don't match, etc. Also, try [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#ConsoleAppender) configuration and check if the config file loads.

Comment: Okay, so both classes seem to load the configuration file you linked to me. So I guess the problem is my custom configuration file ? Yet it seems to respect the formats you linked. Should I rewrite my configuration file ?

Comment: It seems so. Try adding things piece by piece and find what breaks it.

Comment: Okay I'll do that ! I'll keep you updated :) - Thanks !

Comment: Well, it seems that the issue occurs as soon as I define my two loggers. As long as I only have one (the console OR the file) everything is fine. But from the moment I add them both, I only have the file written, and no display in the console (on my new code, not the old one).

Comment: Change `additivity` to true.

Comment: Oh great ! This worked like magic ! Thanks a lot ! I'll mark your message as the answer to my question. I admire your patience haha